# Reduce HTML DIV delay?

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-chrome-extension

I am making a google extension which creates a div overlay. When the following code runs in my background.js, the div overlay takes a long time before it shows up. What should I do in order to make the **div show up faster**?

Here is my code:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function() {
    let startTimeHour;
    let endTimeHour;
    let startTimeMin;
    let endTimeMin;
    let isDisabled;

    defineVariables();

    async function defineVariables(){
        startTimeHour = await getLocalStorageValue("startTimeHour");
        endTimeHour = await getLocalStorageValue("endTimeHour");
        startTimeMin = await getLocalStorageValue("startTimeMin");
        endTimeMin = await getLocalStorageValue("endTimeMin");
        isDisabled = await getLocalStorageValue("isDisabled");
        if(isDisabled != null){
          if(!isDisabled){ //if extension is enabled
            getStuff(); //than load the data
          }
        }
        
    }

function getStuff(){
    setOverlay();  
}, {url: [{urlMatches : 'https://mail.google.com/'}]});
```

Comment: what are you using those varaibles that you get in define variables for? do you need them for the function getStuff?

Comment: Assuming getLocalStorageValue is fast, the problem is not obvious from the code so I guess `setOverlay` is a problem or the fact that you're using onDOMContentLoaded (try with onCommitted). Either way, you need to learn how to use the built-in devtools to debug and [analyze performance of the code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance).

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu Yes, Is use those variables for conditionals in the function getStuff()

Comment: @wOxxOm I inspected the console, and I get the following error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: @wOxxOm I also get this error:
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received